# How to push the array having the same value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
"permissions" => array:4 [▼
      0 => array:8 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "UserIndex"
        "desc" => "查看所有用户"
        "category_id" => 1
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
        "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
        "category" => array:2 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "name" => "用户"
        ]
      ]
      1 => array:8 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "UserDelete"
        "desc" => "删除用户"
        "category_id" => 1
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
        "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
        "category" => array:2 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "name" => "用户"
        ]
      ]
      2 => array:8 [▼
        "id" => 3
        "name" => "UserInfo"
        "desc" => "查看用户"
        "category_id" => 1
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
        "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
        "category" => array:2 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "name" => "用户"
        ]
      ]
      3 => array:8 [▼
        "id" => 4
        "name" => "ActivityIndex"
        "desc" => "查看所有活动"
        "category_id" => 2
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
        "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
        "category" => array:2 [▼
          "id" => 2
          "name" => "活动"
        ]
      ]
```

As u can see, the array has a key called 'permissions', it also has four (maybe more) sub-arrays. In these sub-arrays, they have the 'category_id' key which is linked to the 'category' key's 'name'. What i want to do is to push the same 'category_id' key arrays to an new array. The output should be like this:

```
"permission" => array:2[
 "用户"=> array:3[
   [
     "id" => 1
     .....
   ],
   [
     "id"=> 2
   ],
   [
    "id"=>3
   ]
  ],
  "活动"=> array:1[
   [
    "id" => 4
   ]
   ]
]
```

Comment: So what is the actual problem? You described what the desired result is. So go, implement a loop iterating over the input array and fill a new output array one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty straight forward, you implement a loop iterating over the input array and fill a new output array one by one:

```
<?php
$input = [
  "permissions" => [
    [
      "id" => 1,
      "name" => "UserIndex",
      "desc" => "查看所有用户",
      "category_id" => 1,
      "created_at" => null,
      "updated_at" => null,
      "pivot" => [],
      "category" => [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "用户"
      ]
    ],
    [
      "id" => 2,
      "name" => "UserDelete",
      "desc" => "删除用户",
      "category_id" => 1,
      "created_at" => null,
      "updated_at" => null,
      "pivot" => [],
      "category" => [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "用户"
      ]
    ],
    [
      "id" => 3,
      "name" => "UserInfo",
      "desc" => "查看用户",
      "category_id" => 1,
      "created_at" => null,
      "updated_at" => null,
      "pivot" => [],
      "category" => [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "用户"
      ]
    ],
    [
      "id" => 4,
      "name" => "ActivityIndex",
      "desc" => "查看所有活动",
      "category_id" => 2,
      "created_at" => null,
      "updated_at" => null,
      "pivot" => [],
      "category" => [
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "活动"
      ]
    ]
  ]
];

$output = [];

array_walk($input["permissions"], function($entry) use (&$output){
    $output[$entry["category"]["name"]][] = $entry;
});

print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [用户] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => UserIndex
                    [desc] => 查看所有用户
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [created_at] => 
                    [updated_at] => 
                    [pivot] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [category] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => 用户
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => UserDelete
                    [desc] => 删除用户
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [created_at] => 
                    [updated_at] => 
                    [pivot] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [category] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => 用户
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => UserInfo
                    [desc] => 查看用户
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [created_at] => 
                    [updated_at] => 
                    [pivot] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [category] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => 用户
                        )

                )

        )

    [活动] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => ActivityIndex
                    [desc] => 查看所有活动
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [created_at] => 
                    [updated_at] => 
                    [pivot] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [category] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => 活动
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Comment: Thx, that what i need. At first, i was thinking about how to control the array index in 'foreach' method, because i want to compare its 'category_id'  one by one, but unfortunately, I can't make the loop to iterate correctly.  I haven't heard about 'array_walk' method,  I think it's time to dig into it.

Comment: You can do exactly the same with a `foreach` loop. I personally prefer the lamda-notation, it often keeps things more clean since temporary iteration variables are not cluttered all over the scope outside the loop. But that is a personal preference.